# Navigate between XML Elements with Same Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I'm working on a C#/ASP.Net project.

Let's say this is an xml document:

```
parent1
    child1 attributeA
    child2 attributeA

parent2
    child3 attributeA
    child4 attributeB
```

I want to navigate with next and previous buttons between anything with attributeA, so if I'm at parent1/child2, next would be parent2/child3 and previous would be parent1/child1.

I can create a new XML Document, I can load it, and I can get the current node, but I don't know about next and previous.

How can I do that? Haven't done xpaths in a while. A LONG while. I looked around here for something similar but either it's not there or I can't find it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do not use xpath and xmldocument.  Using the newer Net Library xml linq it is very simple.

Comment: With xml linq you can get a list of elements with the attribute.  Something like this : doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("attributeA") != null).ToList().  Once you have the list it should be simple to navigate to Previous and Next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MSDN has a nice article about XPaths with great examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

But this code should give you all the nodes that have `attributeA` regardless of where they are nested in the XML:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\path\to\file.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@attributeA]");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    // your code here
}
```

The path `//*[@attributeA]` boils down to:

`//` "one or more levels deep"

`*` "any element"

`[@attributeA]` "with attribute 'attributeA'"